# Python: how to Insert value into table postgresql?

Tags: python, string, postgresql, psycopg2

how to format the string to insert it into a table in postgresql?
example I have the sql:

```
req="INSERT INTO table_a values('%s','%s','%s','%s')"
```

and the values

```
values=["Socit d'Invest Variable", '6465', 'hg', 'fk_id']
cursor.execute(req,tuple(values))
```

I get the error :

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "Socit"
LINE 1: ...column0, column1, column2, column3) Values (''Socit d'Invest...
```

any Idea how to change the string from using a single quote `'` to a double quote `"` ?

Comment: What version of psycopg2 are you using? It should automatically escape it for you. Have a look at the example from the docs: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: it's an error in the quote  when formating string  look at  the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error was in the req

```
req="INSERT INTO table_a values('%s','%s','%s','%s')"
```

must be without quote `'`

```
req="INSERT INTO table_a values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use backslash to escape your singlequote in the string for executing query correctly, so either use:

```
values = ['Socit d\'Invest Variable', '6465', 'hg', 'fk_id']
```

or

```
values = ["Socit d\'Invest Variable", '6465', 'hg', 'fk_id']
```

should be working

Comment: @m3asmi How about use `req="INSERT INTO table_a values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"` ?

Comment: @m3asmi Nice! I should have noticed that earlier :p